# Does a creature with DR/alignment bypass DR/magic?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage-reduction

The natural attacks of a creature with DR/x, bypass DR/x. Additionally, high enhancement bonuses bypass DR/ certain materials and alignments.

DR/ weapon type (bludgeoning, piercing, slashing) forcibly needs that kind of damage.

So far everything seems fine.

However, there are some powerful creatures with DR/alignment + material (typically, demons and devils). Would their natural attacks bypass DR/magic? It seems not to, according to RAW, but DR/magic is way "lesser" a characteristic than DR/alignment, so it seems rather strange to me if that is the case.

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No.

The [Damage Reduction (DR) rules from the Bestiary](https://www.aonprd.com/UMR.aspx?ItemName=Damage%20Reduction) only states:

> A creature with an alignment subtype (chaotic, evil, good, or lawful) can overcome this type of damage reduction with its natural weapons and weapons it wields as if the weapons or natural weapons had an alignment (or alignments) that matched the alignment subtype(s) of the creature.

This means that they only overcome the DR/Alignment for their attacks, and only if they have that alignment subtype. This is likely due to their essence being that alignment since [outsiders](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/Creature-types/#Outsider) are partially composed of the essence of a plane.

The [Damage Reduction Rules from the Core Rulebook](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Damage%20Reduction&Category=Special%20Abilities) only have rules for Weapon Enhancement bonuses overcoming different types of DR.

This means that no, they do not ignore DR/Magic when attacking.